# boost::geometry can't recognize that three points are in line (boost::geometry::difference fails)

Tags: c++, boost, distance, boost-geometry, closest-points

I have a complex polyline processing using boost::geometry where I need to do boolean operations with them. I got a strange situation, when boost::geometry can't see that 3 points are all in line and fails to subtract a linestring made with 3 points that are colinear (according to boost::geometry itself) from a linestring made with 2 same endpoints (without the middle one).

Shouldn't the result of subtraction of 2 linestrings be empty if they lay one over another?

```cpp
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

using Number = double;
typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<Number> point_type;

typedef bg::model::linestring<point_type> linestring_type;
typedef bg::model::multi_linestring<linestring_type> multilinestring_type;
typedef bg::model::segment<point_type> segment_type;
    
int main() {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(17);
    
    point_type p1{ 41.746999534390177, 58.355029632348561 };
    point_type pc{ 41.803915890274112, 58.454652240833830 };
    point_type p2{ 41.856075653483821, 58.54593925181792 };

    linestring_type ls1{ p1, p2 };
    linestring_type ls2{ p1, pc, p2 }; // same as ls1 endpoints with a center point which is slightly off

    auto d1 = bg::distance(pc, ls1);
    std::cout << "Distance between Point pc " << bg::wkt(pc) << "and line ls1 " << bg::wkt(ls1) << " is " << d1 << std::endl;

    // now project pc onto ls1
    bg::model::segment<point_type> sout;
    bg::closest_points(pc, ls1, sout);
    point_type pc_proj = sout.second;

    // check if pc_proj is on ls1 (expect zero distance since it is the result of the projection)
    auto d2 = bg::distance(pc_proj, ls1); // should be 0
    std::cout << "Distance between Point pc_proj " << bg::wkt(pc_proj) << "and line ls1 " << bg::wkt(ls1) << " is " << d2 << std::endl;

    //now, create another linestring where all three points should be in line and aligned with ls1
    linestring_type ls2_proj{ p1, pc_proj, p2 }; // same as ls2 with the aligned with ls1 center point 

    // the idea is that since all the points of ls2_proj lie on ls1, the difference should be empty
    multilinestring_type output1;
    boost::geometry::difference(ls1, ls2_proj, output1);

    // oops, non-empty difference
    std::cout << "Difference ls1 - ls2_proj: " << std::endl;
    for (auto& p : output1)
        std::cout << bg::wkt(p) << "\n";

    // and if we ask whether pc_proj is covered by ls1, it is not. But why?
    if (!bg::covered_by(pc_proj, ls1))
    {
        std::cout << "Point " << bg::wkt(pc_proj) << " is not on ls1, but distance is: " << d2 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Distance between Point pc POINT(41.803915890274112 58.45465224083383)and line ls1 LINESTRING(41.746999534390177 58.355029632348561,41.856075653483821 58.54593925181792) is 2.5817835214104254e-06
Distance between Point pc_proj POINT(41.803918131966284 58.454650960044091)and line ls1 LINESTRING(41.746999534390177 58.355029632348561,41.856075653483821 58.54593925181792) is 0
Difference ls1 - ls2_proj: 
LINESTRING(41.746999534390177 58.355029632348561,41.856075653483821 58.54593925181792)
Point POINT(41.803918131966284 58.454650960044091) is not on ls1, but distance is: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/difference/difference_3.html) states that behaviour is defined for:

| Case | Behavior |
| --- | --- |
| areal (e.g. polygon) | All combinations of: box, ring, polygon, multi_polygon |
| linear (e.g. linestring) / areal (e.g. polygon) | A combinations of a (multi) linestring with a (multi) polygon results in a collection of linestrings |
| linear (e.g. linestring) | All combinations of: linestring, multi_linestring; results in a collection of linestrings |
| pointlike (e.g. point) | All combinations of: point, multi_point; results in a collection of points |
| Other geometries | Not yet supported in this version |
| Spherical | Not yet supported in this version |
| Three dimensional | Not yet supported in this version |

Now, playing around with the code a bit led me to suspect floating point inaccuracies: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c9476beca299c33)**

This made me think of alternative appraoches. The simplest appears to be [`simplify`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/simplify/simplify_3.html) which appears to work well, at least for a number of coordinate types:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9796d6265815de0)**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Number, intmax_t Scale = 1> void do_test() {
    namespace bg = boost::geometry;

    using point_type      = bg::model::d2::point_xy<Number>;
    using linestring_type = bg::model::linestring<point_type>;

    point_type const p1(41.746999534390177 * Scale, 58.355029632348561 * Scale);
    point_type const pc(41.803915890274112 * Scale, 58.454652240833830 * Scale);
    point_type const p2(41.856075653483821 * Scale, 58.54593925181792 * Scale);

    linestring_type const ls1{p1, p2};
    linestring_type const ls2{p1, pc, p2}; // center point slightly off

    linestring_type out;
    bg::simplify(ls2, out, 1e-4 * Scale);

    std::cout << " --- simplification equals ls1? " << bg::equals(out, ls1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "          ls1: " << bg::wkt(ls1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "          out: " << bg::wkt(out) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(17) << std::boolalpha;

    do_test<intmax_t, 100'000'000>();
    do_test<long double>();
    do_test<double>();
}
```

Prints

```
 --- simplification equals ls1? true
          ls1: LINESTRING(4174699953 5835502963,4185607565 5854593925)
          out: LINESTRING(4174699953 5835502963,4185607565 5854593925)
 --- simplification equals ls1? true
          ls1: LINESTRING(41.746999534390177 58.355029632348561,41.856075653483821 58.54593925181792)
          out: LINESTRING(41.746999534390177 58.355029632348561,41.856075653483821 58.54593925181792)
 --- simplification equals ls1? true
          ls1: LINESTRING(41.746999534390177 58.355029632348561,41.856075653483821 58.54593925181792)
          out: LINESTRING(41.746999534390177 58.355029632348561,41.856075653483821 58.54593925181792)
```

Another alternative might be to allow for a tolerance "zone" by applying [`buffer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/buffer/buffer_4.html) before querying the `covered_by` relation. I'm not sure which of the approaches I expect to be more optimal, but I suspect it will be the `simplify` approach.

---

> Note, per the docs, `simplify` might lead to self-intersections. You
> might find the `check` helper from my [first
> listing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c9476beca299c33) handy:
>
> ```
> auto check = [](auto& geo) {
>     if (std::string reason; !bg::is_valid(geo, reason)) {
>         std::cout << "Trying to correct " << bg::wkt(geo) << " reason: " << reason << "\n";
>         bg::correct(geo);
>         if (!bg::is_valid(geo, reason))
>             std::cout << " -- failed: " << reason << "\n";
>         else
>             std::cout << " -- result: " << bg::wkt(geo) << "\n";
>     }
> };
> ```